# change or disable modifier key (alt) which activates the application menubar?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there any way to either globally change the modifier key which activates the application menu bar from `alt-` to something else, or if not, at least to globally disable it?

I use a mac for work and I pretty much only run Firefox and Sublime Text3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop (unity). Both apps allow for changing keyboard shortcuts, either natively or via extensions, and I can get the shortcuts *close* to my mac, but you can't setup shortcuts such as `alt-t` to open a new tab in Firefox, as that pulls up the 'Tools' menu.

Any help would be appreciated - it's obviously not a huge priority, but this itch has been bugging me long enough that I'm finally scratching it - it sort of feels like my .emacs are out of sync or I have different versions of emacs running on the different machines :(

Answer (score 1):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager via Ubuntu Software Center or terminal: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`. 
Then open CompizConfig and go to *Ubuntu Unity Plugin > General > Key to show the menu bar while pressed*, and change it. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Install Compiz With Extras

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra -y
```

Then open CompizConfig and go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin > General > Key to show the menu bar while pressed, and change it.

Comment: hmm it seems both you and @PaulB answered the question the way I phrased it, but I guess I phrased it wrong. the fix changes which key displays the application menubar, but alt-F still opens up the File menu.  not sure if these are application-level bindings of if they'll work with <modifier>-F where there is some sort of system-level binding for the application menu sub-menus. I'm gonna have to do some more research and either edit my question or give up. thanks for your help though

Comment: So to clarify, your looking for an application level binding as opposed to a system level binding?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you know if alt-<first letter of menu> is provided by the system, or if applications have to set those key bindings up.